# Where to launch the Google Cloud SQL proxy?

Tags: proxy, configuration, google-cloud-sql, launch

I am having problems because the proxy dies, maybe it is because I launch it from the console, I am a novice with Cloud SQl.

Google Cloud Storage mounted it on the instance configuration page in the custom metadata section with the key 'startup-script'. That's the good place to launch Cloud SQL proxy too?

I've also seen it launch by console:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=xxx:us-central1:my-instance=tcp:3306 &
and
nohup ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=xxx:us-central1:my-instance=tcp:3306 &
```

Thinking about it starting automatically on reboot, what's the good way?

I use an instance with Debian 9

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: I use an instance with Debian 9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install the Cloud SQL Proxy on `/usr/local/bin directory`

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy
sudo chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy
```

The best way to initialize the Cloud SQL Proxy is by using a systemd service

> A Linux service is an application (or set of applications) that runs
>   in the background waiting to be used

1.- Create this file `/etc/systemd/system/cloud-sql-proxy.service`

Please replace this string [`<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>`](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy#start-proxy) with your instance connection name , for example: 
`myproject:myregion:myinstance`

```
[Unit]
Description=Connecting MySQL Client from Compute Engine using the Cloud SQL Proxy
Documentation=https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine
Requires=networking.service
After=networking.service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/var/run/cloud-sql-proxy -instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:3306
Restart=always
StandardOutput=journal
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2.- run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

3.- run `sudo systemctl enable cloud-sql-proxy`

4.- run `sudo systemctl start cloud-sql-proxy`

For additional information please check this [guide](https://gist.github.com/ErikSaunier/e8ff253acc8d18a57192d53b6850300f)

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks JAHDZP. I implemented it when you answered and since then it has not failed again. I have saved a lot of headaches with your help.